# What is the pattern in this sequence of fractions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

1/2, 1/2, 5/8, 5/7, 17/22, 13/16,...

I notice the top numbers are all primes but could not find how that helps. At first I thought maybe it is similar to a Fibonnaci type sequence because of the first two fractions, but I couldnt find a way to extend that to the 3rd term and beyond. I tried also writing as linear combination of the previous two and looking for pattern but did not find anything. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Where do these come from?

Comment: there is not enough information in this question for a sensible answer.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I am trying to find the next term of the sequence.

Comment: the next term could be anything, the problem is not well defined.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker what am I missing? This is a contest problem. There is an answer but I just can’t find it.

Comment: Note: when stating a problem with a source, include that source.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling with [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C4%2C8%2C14%2C22%2C32&sort=&language=english&go=Search) I get
$$
\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+2},\qquad n=0,1,2,3,4,5
$$
so I guess the next term is
$$
\frac{6^2+1}{6^2+6+2} = \frac{37}{44}
$$

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I went to OEIS and I didn’t see how it would detect fractional sequences. How did you do that?

Comment: I did the numerators in OEIS, it said: largest odd divisor of $n^2+1$.  So I tried numerator $n^2+1$.  Then what would the denominator be to match the given sequence?  Then I looked that up in OEIS (linked in the question).

Comment: The question as stated is unsolvable.  Maybe a better version would be: how can I use OEIS to conjecture a formula for this sequence?

Comment: Okay thanks Gerald

Comment: That works but I don’t see how someone would find this with pen and paper. I have read about the method of finite differences. Would this be the correct approach?

Comment: Finite differences works for a polynomial, which this is not.